# Question 20762990 at Stackoverflow on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Is the question [*get switch port utilization or depth of switch port queue/buffer*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20762990/1309352) on-topic on this site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned: yes. Extreme x450t-48 is professional networking equipment, the questions asked about SNMP and queueing aren't that complex but still on topic.